# Recommended code to upload byte[] to Azure file storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage-files

I am unable to find examples from Microsoft on the correct use of the CloudFile class to upload a file to Azure file storage from within an MVC app. Microsoft's documentation shows the [Cloud​File.​Upload​From​Byte​Array​Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfile.uploadfrombytearrayasync) method. Since I have the file contents as a byte[], UploadFromByteArrayAsync seems to be the right method to save the file contents to a file location on an Azure share.

But the CloudFile class also has beginupload and endupload [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfile). Under what conditions would I need to use these methods?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the correct way to use these methods?

As far as I know, UploadFromByteArrayAsync method will return a task that performs an asynchronous operation to upload the contents of a byte array to a file.

It will transfer the data asynchronously to the could file.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
     "connectionstring");
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("filesharename");

            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();


            int size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            Random rand = new Random();
            rand.NextBytes(buffer);

            CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference("Log3.txt");

             file.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

BeginUploadFromByteArray method begin an asynchronous operation to upload the contents of a byte array to a file.

By using this method, your program will transfer the data asynchronously to the could file as UploadFromByteArrayAsync.

If you want to use method, you need create a callback method to receive notification when the asynchronous operation completes.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
     "connectionstring");
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("fileshare");

            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();


            int size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            Random rand = new Random();
            rand.NextBytes(buffer);

            CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference("Log3.txt");

            //This string will pass to the callback function
            string result = "aa";

            //Begins an asynchronous operation to upload the contents of a byte array to a file. If the file already exists on the service, it will be overwritten.
            var res = file.BeginUploadFromByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ProcessInformation, result);


        }

        static void ProcessInformation(IAsyncResult result)
        {

            //The callback delegate that will receive notification when the asynchronous operation completes.
            string Name = (string)result.AsyncState;

            //this Name is aa
            Console.WriteLine(Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Complete");
        }
```

EndUploadFromByteArray method will wait for the BeginUploadFromByteArray method execute completely.

About how to use it, you could refer to below codes:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // TableTest();
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
     "connectionstring");
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("fileshare");

            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();


            int size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            Random rand = new Random();
            rand.NextBytes(buffer);

            CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference("Log3.txt");

             file.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            string result = "aa";

            //Begins an asynchronous operation to upload the contents of a byte array to a file. If the file already exists on the service, it will be overwritten.
            var res = file.BeginUploadFromByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ProcessInformation, result);

            //Ends an asynchronous operation to upload the contents of a byte array to a file.
            //wait for the BeginUploadFromByteArray method execute completely then continue run the codes
            file.EndUploadFromByteArray(res);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void ProcessInformation(IAsyncResult result)
        {

            //The callback delegate that will receive notification when the asynchronous operation completes.
            string Name = (string)result.AsyncState;

            //this Name is aa
            Console.WriteLine(Name);

            Console.WriteLine("Complete");


        }
```

Comment: Where does "ProcessInformation" that you pass to the "BeginUploadFromByteArray" came from?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName.ToString().ToLower());
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
// Retrieve reference to blob
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobRef);
// Upload the file
await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);
```